# Connecting to vimeo video through firebase database issue

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

I am building an app with several video files. I originally stored them in firebase storage and accessed them through putting their links in firebase data base. 
On further inspection i think that storing them in fire base my be a bit expensive. so i looked around for alternative options and figured vimeo might be cheaper to store the videos.

my problem is that when I plug in the url into my firebase database the Vimeo video cannot be viewed. But any url to a firebase video stored in firebase storage will work. Im using avkit to view the videos.

I cannot understand way the url wont work for the vimeo video but will for the firebase stored videos.

my data base looks like this: 
[image]

It has video 1 trying to call a vimeo video (which doesnt work) and video 2 linked to a firebase video which does work.

my code is:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

 class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {



var table = [Videos]()
var ref: DatabaseReference!

@IBOutlet weak var Tableview: UITableView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = Database.database().reference().child("videos")
    ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: {(snapshot) in
        if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
            self.table.removeAll()

            for video in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {

                let Object = video.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                let Title =  Object?["Title"]
                let videolink = Object?["link"]

                //let video = Videos(Title: Title as? String, link: video as? String)
                let video = Videos(Title: Title as? String, link: videolink as? String)
                self.table.append(video)

                self.Tableview.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return table.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = Tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell
    let video: Videos

    video = table[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleLabel.text = video.Title

    return cell

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let videoURL = URL(string: table[indexPath.row].link!) else {
        return
    }

    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)

    let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
    controller.player = player

    present(controller, animated: true) {
        player.play()
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please share your Vimeo video URL?

Comment: https://vimeo.com/316378587

Comment: In firebase it was down as https://vimeo.com/31637858764 for some reason but i took the 64 out and it still doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use that link for AVPlayer, it is a web link, not a media link. To retrieve the media link from a Video post, you should use [VimeoNetworking](https://github.com/vimeo/VimeoNetworking/) or [HCVimeoVideoExtractor](https://github.com/superm0/HCVimeoVideoExtractor).

If you want to use HCVimeoVideoExtractor, here the code:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://vimeo.com/[video_id]")!
HCVimeoVideoExtractor.fetchVideoURLFrom(url: url, completion: { ( video:HCVimeoVideo?, error:Error?) -> Void in                

if let err = error { return }
guard let vid = video else { return }

if let videoURL = vid.videoURL[.Quality1080p] {
    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerController.player = player
    self.present(playerController, animated: true) {
        player.play()
    }
}                            
})
```

You can not retrieve the URL extracted and put it on Firebase, because Video embedded video link is "session", which mean it contains a token that expire after an amount of time.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The video links must change do they? HCVimeoVideoExtractor to get the url. i plugged the url into firebase and it worked. I came back 24hrs later and the link didnt work. So i ran the HCVimeoVideoExtractor again and it produced a different link to my video. the old link didnt work. so i plugged the new link into firebase and it works. im wondering now if i come back tomorrow will it produce a new link for my video....?

Comment: @pete800: I don't think you should put the url extracted on Firebase, because it is expired after an amount of time. I suggest you to keep Firebase as it is right now, then use that web link to extracted the media URL and play it on client side. I also updated my answer.